# 2 or more Tiny Tables in one html page

Tags: jquery

How can I use two or more tiny table plugin in one html page? I made a separate php file per table but when I included the .php files in the main page, the only working table is the first one.

1st Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../javascript/tinytable2/style.css"/>
<div id="tablewrapper">

    <div id="tableheader">

        <div class="search">

            <select id="columns_areaLeader" onchange="sorter.search('query_areaLeader')"></select>

            <input type="text" id="query_areaLeader" onkeyup="sorter.search('query_areaLeader')" />

        </div>

        <span class="details">

            <div>Records <span id="startrecord_areaLeader"></span>-<span id="endrecord_areaLeader"></span> of <span id="totalrecords_areaLeader"></span></div>

            <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">reset</a></div>

        </span>

    </div>
    <table cellspacing='0' id='table_areaLeader' cellpadding='0' class='tinytable'></table>
     <div id="tablefooter">
     <div id="tablenav_areaLeader">
     <div>


     </div>

            <div>

                <select id="pagedropdown_areaLeader"></select>

            </div>

            <div>

                <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>

            </div>

           </div>

        <div id="tablelocation">

            <div>

                <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">

                <option value="5">5</option>

                    <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>

                    <option value="20">20</option>

                    <option value="50">50</option>

                    <option value="100">100</option>

                </select>

                <span>Entries Per Page</span>

            </div>

            <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage_areaLeader"></span> of <span id="totalpages_areaLeader"></span></div>

        </div>
```

```
</div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table_areaLeader',{

    headclass:'head',

    ascclass:'asc',

    descclass:'desc',

    evenclass:'evenrow',

    oddclass:'oddrow',

    evenselclass:'evenselected',

    oddselclass:'oddselected',

    paginate:true,

    size:10,

    colddid:'columns_areaLeader',

    currentid:'currentpage_areaLeader',

    totalid:'totalpages_areaLeader',

    startingrecid:'startrecord_areaLeader',

    endingrecid:'endrecord_areaLeader',

    totalrecid:'totalrecords_areaLeader',

    hoverid:'selectedrow_areaLeader',

    pageddid:'pagedropdown_areaLeader',

    navid:'tablenav_areaLeader',

    sortcolumn:1,

    sortdir:1,

    sum:[8],

    avg:[6,7,8,9],

    columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],

    init:true

         });

       </script>
```

2nd Exapmple

Records - of 

                reset

            

        

       
         
         


                

                    

                

                

                    view all

                

    

            

                

                    

                    5

                        10

                        20

                        50

                        100

                    

                    Entries Per Page

                

                Page  of

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/tinytable/script.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">

var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table_parishPriest',{

    headclass:'head',

    ascclass:'asc',

    descclass:'desc',

    evenclass:'evenrow',

    oddclass:'oddrow',

    evenselclass:'evenselected',

    oddselclass:'oddselected',

    paginate:true,

    size:10,

    colddid:'columns_parishPriest',

    currentid:'currentpage_parishPriest',

    totalid:'totalpages_parishPriest',

    startingrecid:'startrecord_parishPriest',

    endingrecid:'endrecord_parishPriest',

    totalrecid:'totalrecords_parishPriest',

    hoverid:'selectedrow',

    pageddid:'pagedropdown_parishPriest',

    navid:'tablenav',

    sortcolumn:1,

    sortdir:1,

    sum:[8],

    avg:[6,7,8,9],

    columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],

    init:true

});

      </script>
```

Comment: Write your source code here, so we can where is exact problem. Probably variable overload

Comment: http://caritasnovaliches.com/Pages/Caritas%20Coordinator/TableSelectAreaLeader.php  -- here is the link of one of the table http://caritasnovaliches.com/Pages/Caritas%20Coordinator/TableSelectParishPiest.php -- here is the link of another table i cant paste the source code here..

Comment: when I try it individually it works..

Comment: I need to see the source code, edit your question above and put source code there both of file

Answer (score 0):

```
rename id's for second table n wrapper, plus the css
in the second table, user .sorter2() calls
e.g.

var sorter2;
var sorter;

function initSorter(){
    sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns',
        currentid:'currentpage',
        totalid:'totalpages',
        startingrecid:'startrecord',
        endingrecid:'endrecord',
        totalrecid:'totalrecords',
        hoverid:'selectedrow',
        pageddid:'pagedropdown',
        navid:'tablenav',
        sortcolumn:1,
        sortdir:1,
        sum:[8],
        avg:[6,7,8,9],
        columns:[{
            index:7,
            format:'%',
            decimals:1
        },{
            index:8,
            format:'$',
            decimals:0
        }],
        init:true
    });
}

//idNo for new table
function initSorterTableIdPlusNo(tableid, idNo){        
    sorter2 = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter2', tableid,{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns'+idNo,
        currentid:'currentpage'+idNo,
        totalid:'totalpages'+idNo,
        startingrecid:'startrecord'+idNo,
        endingrecid:'endrecord'+idNo,
        totalrecid:'totalrecords'+idNo,
        hoverid:'selectedrow'+idNo,
        pageddid:'pagedropdown'+idNo,
        navid:'tablenav'+idNo,
        sortcolumn:1,
        sortdir:1,
        init:true
    });
}


<div style="width: 90%" id="tablewrapper2">
                                    <font color="blue">Un-ticked Supplier(s) will be removed</font>
                                    <div id="tableheader2">
                                        <div class="search">
                                            <select id="columns2" onchange="sorter2.search('query2')"></select>
                                            <input style="width: 150px" type="text" id="query2" onkeyup="sorter2.search('query2')" />
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="details">
                                            <div>Records <span id="startrecord2"></span>-<span id="endrecord2"></span> of <span id="totalrecords2"></span></div>
                                            <div><a href="javascript:sorter2.reset()">reset</a></div>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <table width="80%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table2" class="tinytable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                                                <th width="6%" scope="col"><h3>No.</h3></th>
                                                <th width="55%" scope="col"><h3>Supplier Name</h3></th>                        
                                                <th class="nosort" width="14%" scope="col"><h3></h3></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>                    
                                            <c:forEach items="${model.supplierslList}" var="supplier" varStatus="status">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        ${status.count}<input name="count" value="${model.supplierSize}" type="hidden"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        ${supplier.facilityunit.facilityunitname}<input name="facilityid" value="${model.facilityid}" type="hidden"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="supplieridHidden${status.count}" value="${supplier.supplierid}"/>
                                                        <input checked type="checkbox" onclick="this.value=0" name="supplierid${status.count}" value="${supplier.supplierid}"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </c:forEach>    
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div id="tablefooter2">
                                        <div id="tablenav2">
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="static/images/pager/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter2.move(-1,true)" />
                                                <img src="static/images/pager/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Previous Page" onclick="sorter2.move(-1)" />
                                                <img src="static/images/pager/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Next Page" onclick="sorter2.move(1)" />
                                                <img src="static/images/pager/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter2.move(1,true)" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <select style="width: 60px" id="pagedropdown2"></select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a onclick="$('#users').attr('height', 'auto'); $('#tabcontent').attr('height', 'auto');" href="javascript:sorter2.showall()">view all</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="tablelocation2">
                                            <div>
                                                <select style="width: 60px" onchange="sorter2.size(this.value)">
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                                    <option value="100">100</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage2"></span> of <span id="totalpages2"></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <table style="width: 60%" align="center">
                                    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><div id="errormsg"></div>
                                            <input class="RoundButton" type="button" name="b1" value="Remove Intenal Supplier" onClick ="
                                                ajaxSubmitData('removeInternalSuppliers.htm', 'assignDIV', $('#unAssignSupplier').serialize(), 'POST');"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="RoundButton" name="cancel" type="reset"  id="cancel" value="Refresh" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                </div>
```